# why the Terminal dont recognize my code in c#

Tags: c#

Why doesn't the TERMINAL execute the command I gave it and it doesn't recognize the name of the project?

[image]

I tried to run the command: project1 bundle --output bundleFile.txt and create a new file that will run for me and it does not recognize the name of my project

Comment: try `cd project1` in the terminal first and then run your command.

Comment: It is possible you didn't place the solution and project in the same directory when creating new project, hence the error.

Comment: Typically the name of a file without the extension or absolute/relative path won't work in PowerShell. Try using the absolute path of the executable. Or, don't use PowerShell at all and instead set the command line arguments in Visual Studio itself so you can debug your app as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project builds an executable, you might need to do

```bash
./project1.exe bundle --output bundleFile.txt
```

Note the addition of `./` before `project1`, as well as the addition of `.exe` (file extension) after `project1`.

It appears that your terminal is using PowerShell, so to executing something in the current directory, you need to first do `./` to indicate that you are referring to a file in the current directory.